# R adding in a specified number of new rows conditionally based on other column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data set that looks similar to the following except with thousands of rows for several agegroups, time periods and states:

```
state  time_period             gender   agegroup  cases
AL     1/1/2020-1/15/2020      F        10-19     2
AL     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     F        10-19     4
AL     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     F        10-19     5
AL     1/1/2020-1/15/2020      M        10-19     4
AL     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     M        10-19     17
AL     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     M        10-19     29
AK     1/1/2020-1/15/2020      M        20-29     50
AK     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     M        20-29     11
AK     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     M        20-29     29
AK     1/1/2020-1/15/2020      F        20-29     50
AK     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     F        20-29     11
AK     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     F        20-29     29
```

I want to conditionally add new rows based on the number in the cases column and subsequently get rid of the cases column all together. So if the cases column == 2, then I want the state, time period, gender, and age group repeated two times.

So using the top three lines as an example, I want the new data frame to look like the following:

```
state  time_period             gender   agegroup 
AL     1/1/2020-1/15/2020      F        10-19     
AL     1/1/2020-1/15/2020      F        10-19     
AL     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/16/2020-1/30/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     F        10-19     
AL     1/31/2020-2/14/2020     F        10-19
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

```r
out <- dat[rep(seq_along(dat$cases), dat$cases),-5]
head(out,20)
#     state         time_period gender agegroup
# 1      AL  1/1/2020-1/15/2020      F    10-19
# 1.1    AL  1/1/2020-1/15/2020      F    10-19
# 2      AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      F    10-19
# 2.1    AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      F    10-19
# 2.2    AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      F    10-19
# 2.3    AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      F    10-19
# 3      AL 1/31/2020-2/14/2020      F    10-19
# 3.1    AL 1/31/2020-2/14/2020      F    10-19
# 3.2    AL 1/31/2020-2/14/2020      F    10-19
# 3.3    AL 1/31/2020-2/14/2020      F    10-19
# 3.4    AL 1/31/2020-2/14/2020      F    10-19
# 4      AL  1/1/2020-1/15/2020      M    10-19
# 4.1    AL  1/1/2020-1/15/2020      M    10-19
# 4.2    AL  1/1/2020-1/15/2020      M    10-19
# 4.3    AL  1/1/2020-1/15/2020      M    10-19
# 5      AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      M    10-19
# 5.1    AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      M    10-19
# 5.2    AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      M    10-19
# 5.3    AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      M    10-19
# 5.4    AL 1/16/2020-1/30/2020      M    10-19
```

The row names are harmless (and can be reset to simple numbers), but they do indicate (in addition to the actual data) that the first two rows came from row 1, the next four rows came from row 2, etc. (I would not rely on this, I'm just highlighting an artifact that reinforces the claim.

The final row count is as expected:

```r
sum(dat$cases)
# [1] 241
nrow(out)
# [1] 241
```